# Issue - referencing and using BizTalk Schema project from a standard .NET WCF project?

Tags: biztalk

I’m new to BizTalk (2010). I have created a very simple BizTalk schema project with a scheam. The root record name of the schema is “Customer” which has couple of child filed elements (Name & Age). I have a .NET project where I’m referencing the above BizTalk schema. This is how I initialize the schema object:

```
TestSchema.Customer request = new TestSchema.Customer();
```

For reasons, I don’t have visibility to any of the child filed elements available in the schema. For example, I’m expecting request.age & request.Name to work fine. But it’s giving compile time exception.

Here is my schema code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://TestSchema.Customer"
 xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003"   
targetNamespace="http://TestSchema.Customer" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xs:element name="Root">
  <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the C# class generated as part of your BizTalk Schema project - in the IDE, click the "Show all Files" icon abd you'll see a .cs file for you .xsd.

Examine the class represenation of you schema and you should see exactly how its structured.

Also, your root element is still called "Root" not "Customer" and I'd expect that you'd get to Name by creating **request.Customer.Name**...

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more info on what you are trying to do?

It is unusual to instantiate schemas from code in a typical BizTalk scenario. Typically, you would use [XLangMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa577495%28v=bts.70%29.aspx) to represent instances of your schemas in BizTalk and manipulate properties here.

The only properties exposed from the XSD instance are XmlContent and RootNodes.

Comment: Thank you very much. All I'm trying to do is to reuse the contracts (schemas) specified in BizTalk from a .NET project. Sounds like I will have to use XSD.exe to create classes from XSD files using XSD.exe.

Comment: (i.e. Assuming that you need to create an entity representing a message) - you can also use the WCF Publishing Wizard to create WSDL / MEX and then add a reference from Visual Studio - you will then get proxied entities.